# How output is assured in simulation

Tags: c++, algorithm, simulation

I've a problem statement like :

> Zombies have placed themselves at every junction in New York. Each junction 'i' initially has a presence of ai number of zombies. At every timestep each zombie randomly chooses one of its neighboring junctions and walks towards it. Each neighboring junction is choosen by the zombie with an equal probability. In order to safegaurd the citizens of New York we need to find out the number of zombies at every junction after 'k' timesteps.
>
> The network of New York is given as an edge list.

I've the option to input all the nodes and all the edges and `k`
. Now I need the number of zombies in five most populated nodes. Now my question is why this set allways need to be the same?
I mean when I run the program first time suppose I get the output set`{5,5,5,4,4}` But why allways this output needs to be the same?

---

Thanks in advance and I'm new to simulation so I'm sorry If I've asked something absurd. Actually it's a Interviewstreet question and I'm not asking for the solution code.

Comment: +1 for having a programming question that involves zombies. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The zombies move randomly so it won't be the same every time.  It will be somewhat random.  You need to simulate this random movement of zombies.

Comment: for simulating the situaion in every timestep I've used srand() with time.

Comment: @me.deeiip did you initialise the random generator?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes I did that for every timesteps

Comment: @me.deeiip you only need to do it once, but you need to do it properly. Seeding it with a constant value will produce constant results.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not using constant value. I'm initialising with time(0)

Comment: @me.deeiip then you should get changing results

Comment: @JanDvorak No the result is not changing and one more thing i.e. this is a interview street question https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4ff1484963063

Comment: @me.deeiip then you should post your code and input data (as a new question, perhaps?)

Comment: @JanDvorak unfortunately Interviewstreet advise not to post the code in forums.

Comment: @me.deeiip what if you post only the lines relevant to random number generation?

Comment: Note that there is big difference between `five most populated nodes` (which should get very random) and `the amount of zombies in five most populated nodes` (which is much less random but should still vary a little). Also note that degenerate tests will produce results with little randomness even if the simulation is correct.

Comment: @me.deeiip The problem you posted is asking for the *expected* number of zombies. `Output Format: 
No of zombies (rounded of to its nearest integer)`